# Inserted partition key does not map to any partition

Tags: oracle, insert, database-partitioning

I need to insert data from one table to antoher. Both tables are partitioned. When i try to  insert, I get this error: ORA-14400: inserted partition key does not map to any partition.

I found that it probably means that I'm inserting value into table and partition is not defined for it. But I use this code while creating the table:

```
CREATE TABLE CENTRUMADMIN.AUD$_BACKUP2
            TABLESPACE CUZK_BACKUP
            PARTITION BY RANGE (NTIMESTAMP#) 
             (
               PARTITION P_2005 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-1-2006', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) TABLESPACE CUZK_BACKUP
             , PARTITION P_2006 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-1-2007', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) TABLESPACE CUZK_BACKUP
             , PARTITION P_2007 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-1-2008', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) TABLESPACE CUZK_BACKUP
             , PARTITION P_2008 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-1-2009', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) TABLESPACE CUZK_BACKUP
             , PARTITION P_2009 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-1-2010', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) TABLESPACE CUZK_BACKUP
             , PARTITION P_2010 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-1-2011', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) TABLESPACE CUZK_BACKUP
             , PARTITION P_2011 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-1-2011', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) TABLESPACE CUZK_BACKUP
             , PARTITION P_2012 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-1-2013', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) TABLESPACE CUZK_BACKUP
             , PARTITION P_2013 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-1-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) TABLESPACE CUZK_BACKUP
             , PARTITION P_2014_01 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-2-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) TABLESPACE CUZK_BACKUP
             , PARTITION P_2014_02 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-3-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) TABLESPACE CUZK_BACKUP
             , PARTITION P_2014_03 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-4-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) TABLESPACE CUZK_BACKUP
             , PARTITION P_2014_04 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-5-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) TABLESPACE CUZK_BACKUP
             , PARTITION P_2014_05 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-6-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) TABLESPACE CUZK_BACKUP
             , PARTITION P_2014_06 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-7-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) TABLESPACE CUZK_BACKUP
             , PARTITION P_2014_07 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-8-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) TABLESPACE CUZK_BACKUP
            ) 
            AS select * from SYS.AUD$ where 1=2;
```

How it's possible that partition is not defined when I do it like this? I'm inserting from table with billions of rows and data from 2005 till present.

```
INSERT INTO CENTRUMADMIN.AUD$_BACKUP2 SELECT
SESSIONID,
ENTRYID,
STATEMENT,
TIMESTAMP#,
USERID,
USERHOST,
TERMINAL,
ACTION#,
RETURNCODE,
OBJ$CREATOR,
OBJ$NAME,
AUTH$PRIVILEGES,
AUTH$GRANTEE,
NEW$OWNER,
NEW$NAME,
SES$ACTIONS,
SES$TID,
LOGOFF$LREAD,
LOGOFF$PREAD,
LOGOFF$LWRITE,
LOGOFF$DEAD,
LOGOFF$TIME,
COMMENT$TEXT,
CLIENTID,
SPARE1,
SPARE2,
OBJ$LABEL,
SES$LABEL,
PRIV$USED,
SESSIONCPU,
NTIMESTAMP#,
PROXY$SID,
USER$GUID,
INSTANCE#,
PROCESS#,
XID,
AUDITID,
SCN,
DBID,
SQLBIND,
SQLTEXT
FROM ISKN.AUD$_BACKUP;
```

Version of my database is 10.2.0.4.0.

Thanks for answers.

Honza

Comment: What does `select count(*) from iskn.aud$backup where ntimestamp# >= timestamp '2014-08-01 00:00:00'` return? The partition named `P_2011` also looks wrong as it is defined as: `LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-1-201'' `. Is that a copy and paste error, or is it really defined like that?

Comment: Also check that you don't have any NULL values in ntimestamp# of source table.

Comment: Thanks for tip, there are a lot NULL values in ntimestamp#